# My Google cloud instance always in Runnable state and going to running state

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, mysql

I have created a google cloud sql instance.Following are the configurations set:

- IPv4 address  -> 173.194.247.217
- IPv6 address  ->2001:4860:4864:1:3f64:544:3d9d:32ca
- Database version  -> MySQL 5.5
- Region->  Asia
- Backup window->   2:30 AM — 6:30 AM
- Binary log->  Disabled
- File system replication-> Synchronous
- Preferred location->  None
- Tier->    D0
- Pricing plan->    Package

My problem is that the instance is always in RUNNABLE state, even after restarting. Also, I have changed the Activation Policy to "always ON".

Due to this, I am not able to ping the the IPv4 address (173.194.247.217) and so not also able to connect via mysql-client or similar application.

Please Help!!

Comment: As per the official documentation (see [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/cloud-sdk) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/instances)) the Runnable state means that your instance is ready to use. Also I was able to ping the instance. Are you behind a proxy? Could you try to ping the IP and use a mysql-client from a GCE instance to discard any networking issue? Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, setting the Activation Policy to "Always ON" means the instance will start running immediately after restarts.Also, it is possible to connect from a public IP to your instance, so, I would check your firewall settings first:

$ mysql --host=173.194.247.217 -uroot -p

Enter password: 

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

$

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect with a Cloud SQL instance via IP, first a password has to be defined for the root account, and in order to do that, you must limit the IPs (either individual (/32) IPs, or whole IP ranges) that can connect to the instance. Therefore:

1: Go to your Cloud SQL instance in the Developers Console, and click "*ACCESS CONTROL*" at the top of the page;

2: In the *Authorized Networks (Optional)* section, click "*Add Authorized Network*", and enter at least the sub-net you'll be connecting from;

3: In the *Set Root Password* section, enter a strong password, then click the "Set" button to the right. Lastly, save your changes.